# Rails 4 most common unique records

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am struggling to both find the solution and the correct terms to describe what I think is a pretty simple scenario:

I have a model column which I am trying to find the most common unique values in my database.  Say I have a Zoo application with an Animals class that has a Species attriute.  I want to know the top 10 species in my Zoo by count.  A scope is what I'm ultimately trying to achieve.

My attempts to add order by count to this has been unsuccessful.  The rails documentation doesn't seem to cover this scenario explicitly:

```
 Animal.group(:species).count.take(10)
```